# I'm looking for SQL to access some unusual data

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for an SQL-only solution for looking up the data in my local database. This is for a nonprofit charity.

I have a MySQL database that contains one table. It has two columns, KY and VL, both strings. These columns represent keys and values. I hope that isn't too confusing. It came from a previous flat-file database system which was ported to MySQL with a PHP GUI.

Each key is like this example: 782310#AD. This has the meaning "the address of client number 782310". There are other complications that I will omit since they are not relevant to a solution. There are about 2900 random client numbers and about 56 different two-letter subkeys (one is AD, which is the client's mailing address).

An example of several rows in my table is:

```
KY           VL 
107781#NA    Melody Smith
107781#EM    melody@gmail.com
615370#NA    Tom Adams
615370#EM    tom.adams@aol.com
```

I want to select and return certain of the columns (NA,EM,DT,client number) of certain of the rows of my table (ordered most recent DT first), one client at a time. I want to do this in SQL with output to a text file (results.txt), one row for each client number, most recent date first.

An example of desired output is:

Melody Smith    03/22/19   107781

My application is to generate a list of my clients' names, email addresses, and dates, ordered by date, for use in emailing general support information in small batches using Gmail.

I don't know SQL very well, so this attempt probably makes no sense:

```
USE databaseName;
WRITE TO FILE 'results.txt' SELECT name,email,date,client FROM tableName WHERE name=client#NA AND email=client#EM AND date=client#DT ORDER DESCENDING BY client#DT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query would look like this

```
SELECT 
    name,email,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%d/%y'),client
    INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/results.txt'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"', ESCAPED BY '\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM tableName 
WHERE name='client#NA' 
   AND email= 'client#EM' 
   AND date= 'client#DT '
ORDER BY client DESC; ;
```

Of course you have to enter a folder for your text file where you have rights to write

Your where clause is unfailiar to me, so that i let it be like it is, you have to put in there values that re vaild,text or dates.

Comment: I haven't had time to try this yet, but thank you. The WHERE clause is meant to use "client" as a variable, and "#NA" as a literal. I doubt it will work as you left it. I will experiment with this tomorrow.

Comment: as i said the term client#EM' is unfamiliar to me but a variable with a correct type will run  like the date this mus be valid date for mysql   like  YYYY-MM-DD,

Comment: I think you have not solved the problem at all. Your solution focuses on formatting the output file, not on collecting all the keys for each single client together. Now that I look at your solution again, I see it cannot possibly work. Can someone else please read the question carefully and show how to do this in SQL please?

Comment: I still don't get where you have your 03/22/19 part From 107781#NA    Melody Smith  or email o  name ok what ever 107781 is, but the rest can not be extracted from #NA

Comment: nbk, I am so sorry that you cannot understand my statement of the problem. I wrote my question as clearly as I am able to. If you have a specific question, let me know and I will clarify. Usually, databases are organized by one row per customer, right? But in my case there are many rows for each customer, organized as I explained in the question. If this isn't the right forum for this question, can someone please recommend a forum where I can get some help?

Comment: Look you want an email but i have to know where it comes from , i can't get it from free air. So you can either provide data in form of ta carete table and data and wanted result. sod that i canbuild a select that works. or you build the select and add the ionto outfile.  to undrstand me, show your question to someone friend or family and see if they could build such a query.

Comment: Looks like my question has been closed, with the usual reason: no reason at all. It can be so unpleasant to try to ask questions here.

Comment: look you didn't provide any data , that can solve your problem. You want to select a email, but where this should come from you didn't answer. Edit your question provide data so that someone can use your information to build your select stement, as long you don't provide information, nobody can help.

Comment: nbk--It is like you didn't read the question at all. I provided a sample row of data. I explained what the KY column means in detail. I said I wanted to get a list of email addresses, but I never said I wanted to "select a email". I provided complete information, but I guess nobody can help. It doesn't matter, since someone rudely closed my question and it will never be answered. I have not seen an SQL tutorial that explains how to solve this sort of problem, so I don't know how to start doing it. I just need a start on a solution, and I can't get it from this website or find another.

Comment: I've added more rows to my example, does that help any? I can't think of any data or information needed to solve this problem that I didn't already give.